# Accesing parent view's object inside from another view

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

When I click the label which is in datebar.xml showPicker() function fired but datepicker view is not visible which in datepicker.xml

Also alert is showing like "oops" Where is my fault? It should be a bug? I am trying to solve this problem since 3 days.

Also onDone function not working that is in datepicker.js on iOS

Thank you in advance. I am testing platfom is iOS and my SDK is 5.1.1 GA

```
<Alloy autoStyle="true">
    <Window>
        <View id="ViewDateBar">
            <Require type="view" src="datebar" id="DateBar" />
        </View>
            <Require type="view" src="datepicker" id="DatePicker" />
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

datebar.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <View id="datebar">
        <Label onClick="ShowDatePicker"/>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

datebar.js

```
var ViewDatePicker = Alloy.createController("datepicker", {
    onDone : function(SelectedDate) {
        Alloy.Globals.JsonQsDateCurrent = SelectedDate;
    }
});

function ShowDatePicker() {
    ViewDatePicker.getView().showDatePicker();
}
```

datepicker.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <View id="datepicker" visible="false">
        <Picker id="picker" />
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

datepicker.js

```
var moment = require("alloy/moment");
var args = arguments[0] || {};
var onDone = args.onDone;

init();

function init() {

    if (OS_IOS) {
        $.picker.setType(Titanium.UI.PICKER_TYPE_DATE);
    }

}

function showDatePicker() {

    if (OS_IOS) {
        //> The iOS Picker will be slide up anddown the screen.
        $.picker.setValue(Alloy.Globals.DateCurrent.toDate());
        $.datepicker.visible = true;

    } else if (OS_ANDROID) {
        //> The Android picker will be a pop-up dialog.
        $.picker.showDatePickerDialog({
            value : Alloy.Globals.DateCurrent.toDate(),
            callback : function(e) {
                if (e.cancel) {
                    Ti.API.info('User canceled dialog');
                } else {
                    done(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

function done(e) {


    if (OS_IOS) {
        hideDatePicker();
        onDone(selectedDate($.picker));
    } else if (OS_ANDROID) {
        if (!e.cancel) {
            onDone(selectedDate(e));
        }
    }

}

function hideDatePicker() {
        $.datepicker.visible = false;

}

function selectedDate(picker) {
    return moment(picker.value);
}

$.datepicker.showDatePicker = showDatePicker;
$.datepicker.hideDatePicker = hideDatePicker;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you define your requires in JavaScript, you can pass a reference to the parent.

window.js:

```
var dateBar = Alloy.createController('datebar', {parent: $.win});
```

I'm not sure why you're dividing up your controllers the way you are. Can you do it like this instead?

```
<Alloy autoStyle="true">
    <Window>
        <View id="ViewDateBar">
            <Require type="view" src="datebar" id="DateBar" />
        </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

databar.xml:

```
<Alloy>
   <View id="datebar">
      <Label onClick="ShowDatePicker"/>
      <Require type="view" src="datepicker" id="DatePicker" />
   </View>
</Alloy>
```

And a final comment: there's not much benefit in defining a datepicker in an XML/TSS/JS controller set. There's not a ton of styling and such that the XML/TSS method would provide you. Why not simply define it in code in the label's click event handler?

Comment: Thank you very much but I can't implement your suggest  and I can't change my app stucture :(

Comment: In your window controller, set a reference to the parent:  `$.DateBar.parent = $.win;`

Comment: I tried like that but I can not access index.xml child by id.